# How to add the same port on different network interface on the same machine?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, port

I have a fedora workstation with 5 physical network interfaces on it.

Four of the network interface have ip `10.10.10.11` `10.10.10.12` `10.10.10.13` `10.10.10.14`.

There runs a filerun serice(port 8081),a gitlab serivce(port 8082), and a transmission(port 8083) service via docker. On my mac, I could access `10.10.10.11:8081` or `10.10.10.12:8081` or `10.10.10.13:8081` or `10.10.10.14:8081`.

What I want is to access filerun via `10.10.10.11:80`, gitlab `10.10.10.12:80`, transmission via `10.10.10.13:80`. How to configure the network?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try using `socac`? Something like `sudo socat TCP-LISTEN:80,fork,bind=10.10.10.11 TCP:10.10.10.11:8081`

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind on the right IP address/interface each service using the same port.
Ports (UDP or TCP) have their own pool per IP address.
You can listen on the same port if you change IP address or protocol (UDP or TCP).
See: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tcp-and-udp-ports-explained/

Alternatively you could use a webserver like NGINX as a reverse proxy and bind the services to a specific ip address and port. Here you would also benefit in caching content and web acceleration for improved performance.

Find out how to set it up: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/